# DIbujar grafico en Canvas. Tkinter, Python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Hola buenas tengo un problema a la hora de representar unos gráficos, estoy usando Python, concretamente la librería Tkinter. Dispongo de una serie de datos en un archivo excel que exporto con python a un dataframe:

```
file = pd.read_excel('Usuarios.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(file)
```

Ahora con esos datos me gustaría extraer varios gráficos (barras, histograma, etc...) y representarlos en una aplicación de escritorio. Como puedo hacer para representarlos en un objeto FRAME o CANVAS en el que pueda hacer scroll hacia abajo y así dibujar 3 o 4 gráficos sin problema ??

Comment: si quieres graficar con varios formas puedes usar la libreria `matplotlib` con el metodo `Figure`, pero no leera datos desde el excel o panda, debes pasarlo a un arreglo o SJON para graficarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es relativamente simple embeber Matplotlib en una App de Tkinter gracias a que Matplotlib provee un backend para ello. En concreto podemos embeber cualquier figura mediante el uso de `matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg` como contenedor.

Personalmente prefiero usar un `Canvas` con un `Frame` en el interior en el cual posicionamos el widgets o widgets (si tenemos varias figuras) `FigureCanvasTkAgg`. Las barras de desplazamiento se asocian al canvas mediante  `Canvas.xview` y `Canvas.yview`. Por otro lado hay que establecer un método que permita redefinir los límites de scroll del `Canvas` cuando el contenido del `Frame` interior cambie.

Dejo un ejemplo muy simple sin usar POO para que te sirva de base:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd


# DataFrame para ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({"Foo": (1, 5, 8, 7, 5, 1, 5),
                   "Bar": (4.25, 5, 6, 1.3, 1, 2.6, 3.7)}
                  )

# Creamos una figura y añadimos algunas gráficas en subplots
fig1 = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(312)
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(313)
df.plot(ax=ax1)
df.plot.bar(ax=ax2)
df.plot.area(ax=ax3)


# Ventana principal
root = tk.Tk()

# Canvas  y barras de desplazamiento
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
hsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)                 
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
hsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

# Vamos a usar un ttk.Labelframe para contener FigureCanvasTkAgg
plot_frame = ttk.Labelframe(canvas, text='Plots')
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=plot_frame, anchor="nw", tags="plot_frame")
plot_frame.bind("<Configure>",
                lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
                )

# Creamos una instancia de FigureCanvas que renderizará la figura
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=plot_frame)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJSevilla me funciona como esperaba pero me surge otro problema. En mi aplicación tengo varias pestañas y ya uso el evento de la ruleta del ratón en una de las pestañas, lo que me ocurre es que teniendo el foco en la pestaña de los gráficos por ejemplo si subo o bajo con la ruleta del ratón realiza la acción en la otra pestaña. Parece como que, aunque cambie de pestaña no tenga el foco en la pestaña que selecciono. No se si me explico bien.

Comment: Hola Alfredo, primero al usar el término "pestañas" supongo que estas usando `ttk.Noteboox`.Si es así no se como has estructurado tu App por lo que es difícil decir que te puede estar fallando, pero yo en este caso suelo siempre encapsular todo el contenido de cada pestaña en un `Frame`,incluidas sus propias barras de desplazamiento. Con esto no debes tener problema alguno con la propagación del evento.Si no consigues solucionarlo edita la pregunta o crea otra con un ejemplo de tu código, no tienes que colocarlo todo, basta con que el ejemplo muestre el comportamiento que describes. Un saludo.